# Dual Boot with Windows 7, Cannot access shared storage from windows

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, shared-folders

I just set up a dual boot with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.
I set them up so they have a common storage space on an HDD, with the OS's on an SSD.

When I save from within Ubuntu, the files don't show up in the folders on the HDD in Windows 7. However, when I save from Windows I can still access those files from within Ubuntu.
WHY?

I followed this tutorial: [How To Harmonize Your Dual-Boot Setup for Windows and Ubuntu](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/35807/how-to-harmonize-your-dual-boot-setup-for-windows-and-ubuntu/)

Thanks!

I have downloaded ethernet/wifi/usb/CD drivers for windows 7 from the internet using Ubuntu but they won't show up in windows to install them! And there is no way of windows being able to get said drivers because of it's complete lack of drivers!

Comment: Do you know what file system you are using for the HDD Data partition? If not, post the output of `sudo parted -l`.

Comment: NTFS, here's the relevant section of the output:

Model: ATA WDC WD7500BPKT-7 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 750GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size   File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  682GB  682GB  ntfs               msftdata